# Format yy-yy to yyyy-yyyy in excel/csv file?

Tags: excel, csv, ms-office, openoffice.org

Hi I have excel file which has year column with following format `yy-yy` with thousands of rows. For example,

```
year
65-67
99-02
03-05
```

Now i want this column to be like this

```
year
1965-1997
1999-2002
2003-2005
```

Is it possible to do in excel ? Kindly help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bit straightforward, but will do the job:

```
=IF(VALUE(LEFT(A2,2))<=YEAR(TODAY())-2000,20,19)&LEFT(A2,2)&"-"&IF(VALUE(RIGHT(A2,2))<=YEAR(TODAY())-2000,20,19)&RIGHT(A2,2)
```

Put in B2 (assuming the first string is in A2) and autofill.

Comment: Happy to help buddy) do not neglect @BonCodigo answer as well for more clear understanding of how dates are stored and maintained within Excel. Good luck!

Comment: Date representation in Excel is not applicable in this case (there is no native duration support. The data is already stored as a string and slicing out the portions is about the best possible solution. The century checks are appropriate, but could also be implemented using judicious scaling and rounding.

Answer (score 2):

Can you try with `Text`. But given that your case there has to be a static concatenating of day and month to the year.

```
Text("01/01/67","yyyy")
```

or

```
TEXT("Jan 67","yyyy")
```

[image]

Reference:

> **How does Excel interprets 2 -digit years**
>
> [To ensure that year values are interpreted as you intended, type year values as four digits (2001, rather than 01). By entering four digits for the years, Excel won't interpret the century for you.](http://office.microsoft.com/en-sg/excel-help/about-dates-and-date-systems-HP005200674.aspx)
>
> **For Microsoft Windows 2000 or later:**
>
> If you are using Microsoft Windows 2000 or later, the Regional Options in Windows Control Panel controls how Excel interprets two-digit years.
>
> **For dates entered as text values:**
>
> When you enter a date as a text value, Excel interprets the year as follows:
>
> - 00 through 29 :    Excel interprets the two-digit year values 00 through 29 as the years 2000 through 2029. For example, if you type the date 5/28/19, Excel assumes the date is May 28, 2019.
> - 30 through 99 :    Excel interprets the two-digit year values 30 through 99 as the years 1930 through 1999. For example, if you type the date 5/28/98, Excel assumes the date is May 28, 1998.

Comment: i dont want date and month, i just want year.Like i given year to year (yy-yy to yyyy-yyyy)

Comment: But in order to get the year, it has to act like a date...so system can recognize it as a proper year from a date... So the ugliest way of doing is to have a static month tagging along and then use `Text` to get the `Year` out..

Comment: Thanks where can i use this format.since i am not well known in excel. kindly give some advice

Comment: You can use this either in Excel cells, as shown in the image or in VBA. Infact I was trying to look for a more robust way to *land in* the year using `serial number`.

Comment: Assume your `67` value is in `Column F2`, then you can write in `Column G2`  `= Text("Jan " & F2, "yyyy")` resulting `1967`

Comment: Interesting. Does this mean that when 2030 comes around, Excel will be broken? Is this the new Y2k030 bug?

Comment: @Floris looking at the article seems like it. However going forward I presume, Microsoft would do the honours accordingly `;)` changes, updates..